# TCSH Prompt Displays Syntax Error Regarding Missing Bracket

Tags: prompt, tcsh

I have set the `prompt` on my machine using the following code:

```
set prompt = " %B%{\033[34m%}`hostname`: %c %D/%w %p :) %b"
```

It outputs my preferred customized display . It looks like :

[image: Custom Prompt]

However when I issue a `echo $prompt` command, it returns `missing ]`. I belive I did properly refer to the [Customization Manual](http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run into one of tcsh's parsing quirks. From the [tcsh manual](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Variable_substitution.html):

> Variable substitution
>   Unless enclosed in ' " ' or given the ':q' modifier the results of variable  substitution may eventually be command and filename substituted.

You have a variable that expands to something syntactically incorrect for filename substitution. You can prevent that substitution by typing `echo "$prompt"` or `echo $prompt:q` .

Example:

```
% set prompt = " %B%{\033[34m%}`hostname`: %c %D/%w %p :) %b"
 host.example.com: ~ 12/Dec 9:46:12am :) echo $prompt:q | cat -v
 %B%{^[[34m%}host.example.com: %c %D/%w %p :) %b
```

Comment: well `echo "$prompt"` and `echo $prompt:q` does give me half answer.

it returns the evaluated value of ``hostname`` and also color.

Comment: You can pipe the echo command through `cat -v` if you want the `\033` character not to show up literally in the output; I've added that to the answer. The `hostname` command is evaluated and substituted (by command substitution) when the `set` command is executed; after that, the characters `\`hostname\`` do not exist in the prompt variable. You can put `%M` in the `prompt` variable if you want the current hostname to be retrieved and printed every time a prompt is printed.